# In C#, how can you implement a method of an interface that has another interface as argument?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

My question is as follows: Is it possible to implement an interface that has a method with another interface as a parameter, where the implementation of this method uses an implemented class of the argument interface?

I created a smallest possible example of the problem:

```
public interface Pos { }

public interface SearchWorld
{
    public IEnumerable<Pos> GetNeighbors(Pos pos);
}

public class PosImp: Pos
{
   public int X{ get; set; }
   public int Y{ get; set; }
}

public class SearchWorldImp : SearchWorld
{
    public IEnumerable<Pos> GetNeighbors(Position pos)
    {
        yield return new Position { X = pos.X+ 1, Y= pos.Y};
    }
}
```

This will result in the error that the GetNeighbors method is not implemented by SearchWorldImp. Is there a way to still keep this kind of abstraction, so that I only need the Pos and SearchWorld interfaces for a depth first search algorithm for example?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Why aren't `X` and `Y` part of the interface `Pos` ?

Comment: How about making `SearchWorld` generic?  e.g. `SearchWorld<TPos> where T: Pos`

Comment: @wohlstad Presumably OP wants different kinds of "positions". 2D positions, 3D positions, polar coordinates, etc.

Comment: `SearchWorldImpGetNeighbors` uses `Position` as parameter while SearchWorld`.GetNeighbors` use `Pos` as parameter! They are considered two different methods.

Comment: @Sweeper in this case why is `SearchWorldImp.GetNeighbors`  treating `pos` asif it has `X` and `Y` ? (I assumed `Position` is a typo for `Pos`, otherwise is not defined in the posted code).

Comment: `GetNeighbors` method declared in `SearchWorld` interface does not accept an argument of type Position.  So that's why you are getting the error. Method in `SearchWorldImpl` is considered a different method. Also, you should prefix the interface names with "I" as per [identifier naming rules and conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names).

Comment: @wohlstad Because that is what OP wants to do, and they are asking how to do that.

Comment: @Sweeper I understand. But it seems to me like this design requires the interface to supply some kind of [abstract] properties to work with ..

Comment: @wohlstad yeah, which is why I suggested what I suggested. If `Pos` doesn't have any requirements, it might as well just be an unconstrained generic type parameter on `SearchWorld`. If it does have other requirements in OP's real code, then `SearchWorld` can have a type parameter constrained to `Pos`.

Comment: @Sweeper I Fixed it with your suggestion (e.g. SearchWorld<TPos> where T: Pos). However, now I have a new problem when I inject SearchWorldImp into my search algorithm (this algorithm takes SearchWorld<Pos> as an argument): "Cannot convert from  SearchWorldImp to SearchWorld<Pos>. I feel like I am going in circles :P

Comment: @J.Somers Your "search algorithm" (I assume this is a method?) Should also be generic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sweeper comments I managed to make it work by making the SearchWorld interface generic.

The goal was to define search algorithms in the most generic way, without any dependencies on class implementations. I replaced the Pos interface with the IEquatable interface. Here is Depth-First search as an example:

```
namespace Search
{
    public interface ISearchWorld<TPOS> where TPOS : IEquatable<TPOS>
    {
        public IEnumerable<TPOS> GetNeighbors(TPOS pos);
    }

    public class DFS<TPOS> where TPOS : IEquatable<TPOS>
    {
        public static bool AreStartPositionAndGoalConnected(ISearchWorld<TPOS> searchWorld, TPOS startPosition, TPOS goal)
        {
            return DFSrec(startPosition, searchWorld, goal, new());
        }

        private static bool DFSrec(TPOS currentPos, ISearchWorld<TPOS> searchWorld, TPOS goal, HashSet<TPOS> discovered)
        {
            if (currentPos.Equals(goal)) return true;
            discovered.Add(currentPos);
            foreach (var neighbor in searchWorld.GetNeighbors(currentPos))
            {
                if (discovered.Contains(neighbor)) continue;
                if (DFSrec(neighbor, searchWorld, goal, discovered)) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```